# React Native can't build APK file

Tags: react-native, gradle, android-emulator, command-prompt

I have successfully build react-native app folder according to this http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started documentation

But, when I am running `react-native run-android` in cmd, it is showing me this -

````
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
9 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 1 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Specified AAPT2 executable does not exist: C:\Users\DE\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\e3571e1615ccf7c32524cbf1a8ed0eb8\aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows\aapt2.exe

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 55s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Specified AAPT2 executable does not exist: C:\Users\DE\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\e3571e1615ccf7c32524cbf1a8ed0eb8\aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows\aapt2.exe

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 55s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\DE\AwesomeApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:75:39)
    at buildAndRun (C:\Users\DE\AwesomeApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:137:41)
    at C:\Users\DE\AwesomeApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:103:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\DE\AwesomeApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:160:7)```
````

Comment: Are you sure that you followed all steps under 'Android development environment' section? If yes, does this behaviour repeat when you retry to do it? Sometimes it builds only from the second time

Comment: yes, I am sure about that...because several days ago I made the other app using the same settings and it had made it successfully..But now it is giving error on making an app

Comment: If you check it in a browser does that file exist? Another thing you can try is deleting the .gradle/caches directory and try building again.

Comment: @Izabela Orlowska I tried it, but the same output is coming

Comment: @AfifaKhan does the file C:\Users\DE\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\e3571e1615ccf7c32524cbf1a8ed0eb8\aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows\aapt2.exe exist? It's possible your antivirus is deleting it as soon as it's downloaded. Please check your firewall/antivirus software.

Comment: @ Izabela Orlowska  thanks for your suggestion....yeah it seems possible that file is deleting..can you tell me how can I shut it

Comment: @ Izabela Orlowska, ok i have added exclusion of `.exe` in windows defender but the file is still deleting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this problem by deleting the cache of `.gradle` folder. The path is `C:\Users\DE\.gradle\caches` . After that, apps are building.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I tried going to the application directory the second one with cmd and running "react-native start". This solved my problem.